# Recusively copy files of a specific pattern and recreate the folders hierarchy

Tags: windows, file-io, command-line

How can I copy a set of files by a specific pattern from a set of deeply structured folders recursively into another folder? Also I need to recreate the folder hierarchy from source folder in the target folder (only that folders, which contain copied files). I need to use standard Windows command-line tools.

This question looks like this one: [How can I recursively copy files of a specific pattern into a single flat folder on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246559/how-can-i-recursively-copy-files-of-a-specific-pattern-into-a-single-flat-folder) ; but in my case I want to keep folder structure, so this script will not do this:

```
for /r %x in (*.dll, *pdb) do copy "%x" targetDir\
```

Comment: What's wrong with `robocopy /s sourceDir targetDir *.dll *.pdb` ?

Comment: What  is `robocopy`?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision is:

```
FOR /r %x in (PATTERN) DO 
     (if not exist TARGET_DIR%~px mkdir TARGET_DIR%~px) & (copy %~x c:\\TARGET_DIR%~px)
```

So, the "secret" is in `%~px` command which gives relative path of copied file, so we should create this relative path in target dir.