# How to recursively copy files and paste them as links to a single flat output folder?

Tags: windows, hyperlink, copy

A similar question was previously addressed in stack overflow here:

[How can I recursively copy files of a specific pattern into a single flat folder on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246559/how-can-i-recursively-copy-files-of-a-specific-pattern-into-a-single-flat-folder)

I would like to do the same task, except the target output would be link files instead of copies of the source.

I tried `xcopy sourcefolder targetfolder /e /b` but that retained the source folder structure and the output files were the actual source files, not links.

I then tried  `xcopy sourcefolder targetfolder /b` but nothing was copied.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly. Do you want to create symlinks / *.lnk files in the `targetfolder`?